# System.Timers.Timer Elapsed event not firing in Windows Service

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, service, timer

I recently purchased a very weak VPS from GoDaddy to test a website I have developed.  I've created a simple service that I would like to trigger every 10 seconds to send pending emails to users from my database.  I've created many services before that used a System.Timers.Timer and I've never had a problem with it.  This is the first service I've installed on the VPS, however.  The timer is simply not firing.  I know this because I keep my own EventLog in a txt file and the Service's OnStart() works and writes to my EventLog.  After that, nothing...  I have tried everything under the sun to get this to work and I just can't.  The mysterious thing is that even a System.Threading.Timer's callback DOES NOT fire.  Could this be an issue with the VPS??  Please don't tell me I'm going to have to put this in a Scheduled Task!! lol

Things I've tried:

Using timer.Enabled instead of timer.Stop.
Using System.Threading.Timer.
Reordering the timer property declarations.
Setting timer.Autoreset to "false" and not stopping timer in Elapsed event.
Installing the service as local system AND as Administrator.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using FieldEncryption;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace EmailsPendingSvc
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer.Interval = 10000;
            timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start();
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Program Files\PHServices\EmailsPendingSvc\EventLog.txt", true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "  --  " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "  --  Service Started.");
            }
        }

        void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Program Files\PHServices\EmailsPendingSvc\EventLog.txt", true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Timer elapsed.");
            }
            timer.Stop();
            // Do Stuff
            timer.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Program Files\PHServices\EmailsPendingSvc\EventLog.txt", true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "  --  " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "  --  Service Stopped.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered just using a background thread with a `Thread.Sleep` between iterations?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Rowland.  I would still need a timer to fire every 10 seconds to check for pending emails in my database

Comment: So why not have a loop with a sleep after each run completes?

Comment: That's bad practice, don't ever do that

Comment: So is using a timer in a service...

Comment: Using try/catch in the Elapsed event handler is a rock-hard requirement, System.Timers.Timer is a very nasty timer and swallows exceptions without a peep.  An obvious failure mode is the logging code throwing an exception, never write to the c:\program files directory.  You are already dead in the water when you run as a 32-bit process, c:\program files (x86) won't have a PHServices subdirectory.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the logging code, it works.  I've used it for years now.  "C:\Program Files (x86)" can have a "PHServices" folder if you add it...  Can we please address the issue at hand??  "timer_Elapsed" is not firing!